# Got ERR_BAN when invoking WeChat for Authorization on Android

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, wechat

I am implementing the "login by WeChat" feature for my Android app.

I followed all the steps on the [official developer guide](http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/mobile/login/guide#login_guide), however,  I am consistently getting the error code ERR_BAN in my onResp function in the WXEntryActivity class.

I wonder what does ERR_BAN mean?
What are the possible root causes?

Answer (score 1):

ERR_BAN error is probably happening because you have added the incorrect app signature.

In order to retrieve the correct signature you must download the Android Signature tool from the following link

https://res.wx.qq.com/open/zh_CN/htmledition/res/dev/download/sdk/Gen_Signature_Android2.apk

Install the app, add your app package id and add the generated key to the we chat admin interface:

https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/index?t=home/index&lang=zh_CN

(hint: use the chrome translate plugin to navigate on the site, as it is in chinese only)

Comment: This information does not exist on WeChat official docs nor plugin official docs.
You can't imagine how you helped me. Thank you very much!!!